# Why &apos; in XML is converted to '

Tags: java, xml, apache-spark

I am reading a XML file using

```
  var df = spark.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rootTag", "rootTag")
    .option("rowTag", "rowTag")
    .schema(mySchema)
    .load(inputFile)
```

Why `&apos;` in the XML is converted to `'`  or `&amp;` to `&`?

Comment: Read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity

Answer (score 1):

Because XML reserve 5 characters :

```
Original character   Escaped character
"                   &quot;
'                   &apos;
<                   &lt;
>                   &gt;
&                   &amp;
```

So as this 5 characters are reserved in XML the way to use it is with the escaped character. So that is why `&apos;` will be ' this in XML there reserved characters in HTML too for example.